# How to swap out a DB from MySQL to SQL Server in a multiple large projects?

Tags: database, mysql, sql-server

Is there a sane way / best practices way to swap out a DB from MySQL to SQL Server in a multiple large projects?  Some of the projects are ASP projects, some of them are windows services, some are standalone windows apps.  I don't think any ORM is used.  I think its just SQL statements all over the place.

Comment: YOu are going to need this: http://www.amazon.com/SQL-Nutshell-OReilly-Kevin-Kline/dp/0596518846/ref=sr_1_2?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1330461974&sr=1-2

Comment: @HLGEM - I've worn out the binding on the pocket guide.

Comment: @JeffO, it really is the most useful book if you need to convert code from one database to another.

Answer (score 5):

Nope, no sane way.  It will require an insane amount of work, testing, unexpected bugs and missed deadlines.
I would recommend:

- Start polishing those tests now.  Or start writing them.
- Look for a commercial product that will help with the data transfer.
- Set up your new area asap and start doing the mapping, just to get an idea of what's involved.
- talk (or post here and Stack Overflow) to folks who know these issues.  Post specific questions about primary keys, indexes, triggers, etc. to start getting a handle on it.
- Make it a project that gets enough resources (several people and several months) to do it.  Make sure you communicate how much work it is - once you yourself a got a better idea (right now you don't).